# SQL - distinct list of hierarchical menus

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sorry about the large post. I have attempted to simplify the data down to the core issue.
I have 2 tables with a lot of duplicate data which I am attempting to optimise/completely restructure.
Am using SQL Server 2008 R2

`Menu`:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [int] NULL,
[Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ActionId] [int] NULL,
[Data] [varchar](500) NULL,
[FormId] [int] NULL,
```

`RootMenu`:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FormId] [int] NULL,
```

Sample data

`Menu`:

```
Id  ParentId  Title   ActionId  Data           FormId
--  --------  ------  --------  -------------  ------
20  1         Title1  17        Data1Filter2   1
21  1         Title2  17        Data2Filter2   1
22  2         Title9  16        RootMenu2      1
23  2         Title5  17        Data3Filter2   1
24  3         Title1  17        Data1Filter2   2
25  3         Title2  17        Data2Filter2   2
26  4         Title9  16        RootMenu2      2
27  4         Title5  17        Data3Filter2   2
28  5         Title1  17        Data1Filter2   3
29  5         Title2  17        Data2Filter2X  3
30  6         Title9  16        RootMenu2      3
31  6         Title5  17        Data3Filter2   3
```

`RootMenu`:

```
Id  Name       FormId
--  ---------  ------
1   RootMenu2  1
2   RootMenu3  1
3   RootMenu2  2
4   RootMenu3  2
5   RootMenu2  3
6   RootMenu3  3
```

There are 3 forms in this sample with a menu hierarchy looking like this:

Menu Structure created  (`Form1`)

```
RootMenu3              
  Title9                    -- as this action is 16 (recursive) it looks up RootMenu2 for Form 1, gets Id=1
    Title1  (Data1Filter2)  -- gets menu items with parentid =1
    Title2  (Data2Filter2)        
  Title5
```

Menu Structure created  (`Form2`)

```
RootMenu3              
  Title9                    -- as this action is 16 (recursive) it looks up RootMenu2 for Form 2, gets Id=3
    Title1  (Data1Filter2)  -- gets menu items with parentid =3
    Title2  (Data2Filter2)        
  Title5
```

Menu Structure created  (`Form3`)

```
RootMenu3              
  Title9                    -- as this action is 16 (recursive) it looks up RootMenu2 for Form 3, gets Id=5
    Title1  (Data1Filter2)  -- gets menu items with parentid =5
    Title2  (Data2Filter2X)        
  Title5
```

`Form1` and `Form2` have an identical hierarchy, but `Form3` is different (has `Data2Filter2X`)

What I need is SQL that will give me the distinct hierarchical menu structure.

I am thinking of combining the `RootMenu` and `Menu` tables into 1 without the reference to `FormId`, and creating a `FormMenu` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormMenu](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [FormId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [MenuId] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

final `Menu` data

```
Id  ParentId  Title   ActionId  Data
--  --------  ------  --------  -------------
20  1         Title1  17        Data1Filter2
21  1         Title2  17        Data2Filter2
22  2         Title9  16        RootMenu2
23  2         Title5  17        Data3Filter2
28  5         Title1  17        Data1Filter2
29  5         Title2  17        Data2Filter2X
30  6         Title9  16        RootMenu2_v2
31  6         Title5  17        Data3Filter2

1  null RootMenu2     1 null  
2  null RootMenu3     1 null 
5  null RootMenu2_v2  3 null 
6  null RootMenu3_v2  3 null
```

final `FormMenu` data

```
Id  FormId  MenuId
--  ------  ------
1   1       1    
2   1       2    
3   2       1    
4   2       2    
5   3       5    
6   3       6
```

If you have read this far, thank you. Can you help me out with SQL to get the end result?

Comment: You should add more tags, such as the database you are using, and maybe the version... is it SQL Server?

Comment: Is there a typo in your examples? Should `RootMenu2` be at the top of the hierarchy, not `RootMenu3`?

Comment: wweicker, I have updated the tags,.

Comment: Ed, RootMenu3 is the top level Root Menu. Note than RootMenu3 has Id 2, which when you look in the Menu table, note that there are 2 entries with that as a parent: Title9 and Title5. Title9 uses RootMenu2 as its root. Sorry about the naming confusion regards the sample Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not confident I've fully understood all the rules of the system, but it seems like the "recursive" (`ActionId` = 16 records) aren't required for this; a query including only the simple relationships (`ActionId` = 17) seems to produce the required output:

test data:

```
DECLARE @menu TABLE
(
[Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [INT] NULL,
[Title] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[ActionId] [INT] NULL,
[DATA] [VARCHAR](500) NULL,
[FormId] [INT] NULL
)

DECLARE @rootmenu TABLE
(
[Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[FormId] [INT] NULL
)

INSERT @menu (Id,ParentId,Title,ActionId,DATA,FormId)
      SELECT 20,1,'Title1',17,'Data1Filter2',1
UNION SELECT 21,1,'Title2',17,'Data2Filter2',1
UNION SELECT 22,2,'Title9',16,'RootMenu2',1
UNION SELECT 23,2,'Title5',17,'Data3Filter2',1
UNION SELECT 24,3,'Title1',17,'Data1Filter2',2
UNION SELECT 25,3,'Title2',17,'Data2Filter2',2
UNION SELECT 26,4,'Title9',16,'RootMenu2',2
UNION SELECT 27,4,'Title5',17,'Data3Filter2',2
UNION SELECT 28,5,'Title1',17,'Data1Filter2',3
UNION SELECT 29,5,'Title2',17,'Data2Filter2X',3
UNION SELECT 30,6,'Title9',16,'RootMenu2',3
UNION SELECT 31,6,'Title5',17,'Data3Filter2',3

INSERT @rootmenu (Id,Name,FormId)
SELECT 1,'RootMenu2',1
UNION SELECT 2,'RootMenu3',1
UNION SELECT 3,'RootMenu2',2
UNION SELECT 4,'RootMenu3',2
UNION SELECT 5,'RootMenu2',3
UNION SELECT 6,'RootMenu3',3
```

And the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.FormId, r.Id AS MenuId
FROM @menu AS m
JOIN @rootmenu AS r
ON r.Id = m.ParentId
WHERE m.ActionId = 17
```

Comment: The Id 17 actions are non-recursive actions (eg like Launch an exe). The Id 16 actions are popup menus, which recurse back to the RootMenu table to pick up the next RootMenu Id. Then the next level of menu items is taken from the Menu table with ParentId of that RootMenu Id. Hope that makes it clearer?

Comment: @AndrewRoberts - so is this answer wrong? If so, why? To do the reformatting I copy/pasted your data into a text editor, ran a regular expression to convert one or more spaces into a comma, then manually added the single quotes. If there had been more data, I would have used a regex to add the single quotes too.

Comment: yes, the answer is wrong - a bit too simple. I have posted another attempt, but I am still not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Ed Harper's temp table script in this answer.
My first and second attempt at getting a set a rows to exclude are not quite right. Second attempt is a lot longer but the same wrong result.

In the end result, I think that I want to only get the parentid 3 rows in the exclusion table as they are duplicates of the parentid1 Rows.
Then I can exclude them from the original Menu table.
I do not want the parentid 5 rows in the exclusion table because the menu rows are distinct from that of parentid 1

```
DECLARE @menu TABLE
(
[Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [INT] NULL,
[Title] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[ActionId] [INT] NULL,
[DATA] [VARCHAR](500) NULL,
[FormId] [INT] NULL
)

DECLARE @rootmenu TABLE
(
[Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
[Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
[FormId] [INT] NULL
)

INSERT @menu (Id,ParentId,Title,ActionId,DATA,FormId)
      SELECT 20,1,'Title1',17,'Data1Filter2',1
UNION SELECT 21,1,'Title2',17,'Data2Filter2',1
UNION SELECT 22,2,'Title9',16,'RootMenu2',1
UNION SELECT 23,2,'Title5',17,'Data3Filter2',1
UNION SELECT 24,3,'Title1',17,'Data1Filter2',2
UNION SELECT 25,3,'Title2',17,'Data2Filter2',2
UNION SELECT 26,4,'Title9',16,'RootMenu2',2
UNION SELECT 27,4,'Title5',17,'Data3Filter2',2
UNION SELECT 28,5,'Title1',17,'Data1Filter2',3
UNION SELECT 29,5,'Title2',17,'Data2Filter2X',3
UNION SELECT 30,6,'Title9',16,'RootMenu2',3
UNION SELECT 31,6,'Title5',17,'Data3Filter2',3

INSERT @rootmenu (Id,Name,FormId)
SELECT 1,'RootMenu2',1
UNION SELECT 2,'RootMenu3',1
UNION SELECT 3,'RootMenu3',2
UNION SELECT 4,'RootMenu3',2
UNION SELECT 5,'RootMenu3',3
UNION SELECT 6,'RootMenu3',4

--non recursive level 1 menu with Root
SELECT DISTINCT m.ParentId,m.Title,m.ActionId,m.DATA
FROM @menu AS m, @rootmenu AS r
where r.Id = m.ParentId
and m.ActionId<>16

--non recursive level 1 menu with Root
SELECT DISTINCT m.ParentId,m.Title,m.ActionId,m.DATA
FROM @menu AS m, @rootmenu AS r
where r.Id = m.ParentId
and m.ActionId=16

--level 1 menu without Root
--SELECT  m.ParentId,m.Title,m.ActionId,m.DATA
--FROM @menu AS m

--level 1 count
SELECT ParentId, COUNT(*) as count from
(
SELECT ParentId as ParentId,Title as Title,ActionId as ActionId,DATA as DATA
FROM @menu m3) as l1
 group by ParentId

 --2nd level menu
SELECT DISTINCT m2.ParentId,m2.Title,m2.ActionId,m2.DATA
FROM @menu AS m, @menu AS m2, @rootmenu AS r,@rootmenu AS r2
where r.Id = m.ParentId
and r2.Id = m2.ParentId
and m.DATA= r2.Name

--initial attempt at exclusion rows
select distinct Level1.* from
(SELECT DISTINCT m2.ParentId as ParentId,m2.Title as Title,m2.ActionId as ActionId,m2.DATA  as DATA
FROM @menu AS m, @menu AS m2, @rootmenu AS r,@rootmenu AS r2
where r.Id = m.ParentId
and r2.Id = m2.ParentId
and m.DATA= r2.Name) 
as Level2 ,
(SELECT DISTINCT ParentId as ParentId,Title as Title,ActionId as ActionId,DATA as DATA
FROM @menu
where ActionId<>16)
 as Level1 
where Level1.Title=Level2.Title 
and Level1.ActionId=Level2.ActionId 
and Level1.DATA=Level2.DATA 
and not Level1.ParentId=Level2.ParentId


 --second attempt at exclusion rows with Counts
select distinct Level1.* from
(SELECT DISTINCT m2.ParentId as ParentId,m2.Title as Title,m2.ActionId as ActionId,m2.DATA  as DATA
FROM @menu AS m, @menu AS m2, @rootmenu AS r,@rootmenu AS r2
where r.Id = m.ParentId
and r2.Id = m2.ParentId
and m.DATA= r2.Name) 
as Level2 
join
(SELECT ParentId, COUNT(*) as count from
(SELECT DISTINCT m2c.ParentId as ParentId,m2c.Title as Title,m2c.ActionId as ActionId,m2c.DATA  as DATA from
@menu AS mc, @menu AS m2c, @rootmenu AS rc,@rootmenu AS r2c
where rc.Id = mc.ParentId
and r2c.Id = m2c.ParentId
and mc.DATA= r2c.Name) as l2
Group by ParentId) as L2Count
 On  L2Count.ParentId= Level2.ParentId,

(SELECT DISTINCT ParentId as ParentId,Title as Title,ActionId as ActionId,DATA as DATA
FROM @menu
where ActionId<>16)
 as Level1 
 join

 (SELECT ParentId, COUNT(*) as count from
(
SELECT ParentId as ParentId,Title as Title,ActionId as ActionId,DATA as DATA
FROM @menu m3
where ActionId<>16) as l1
 group by ParentId) as L1Count
 On  L1Count.ParentId= Level1.ParentId

where Level1.Title=Level2.Title 
and Level1.ActionId=Level2.ActionId 
and Level1.DATA=Level2.DATA 
and not Level1.ParentId=Level2.ParentId
and L1Count.count= L2Count.count
```